# Javascript Recursive Binary Search Function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to build a recursive js function. Anyone having a clear solution please share.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please give details on the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: [You are welcome.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure)

Comment: Unable to use Google?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i have achieved ...

https://jsfiddle.net/21rggjdL/5/

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

function myFunction(item, value, start, end) {
            var mid = Math.floor((start + end)/2);       
    while(mid>=0 && start <= end){
    if(item[mid] === value){
        return item[mid] + " at index "+ mid;
    }
        else if(item[mid] < value){
            console.log("Inside <");
        return myFunction(item, value, mid + 1, end);
    }
        else if(item[mid] > value){
            console.log("Inside >");
        return myFunction(item, value, start, mid - 1);
    }
    }
        return -1;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(array, 10, 0, array.length -1);
```

Comment: Yes it is working properly, just one thing ... should i remove the elements from the array after each iteration by splice() method? Will it improve the performance or not.

Comment: It's called Binary *Search*. A search should not modify the array in any way. Also you should replace your `while` loop with an `if`.